# Where to insert try/catch in java code

Tags: java, try-catch

I am very new to Java and can't understand where try/catch needs to go in the following code.  There is much more to this project, however this is the problem area

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Customer";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String ln = rs.getString("FirstName");
        String ln1 = rs.getString("LastName");
        System.out.println(ln + " " + ln1);
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/ might be worth a read

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 7+, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

An example from the documentation link:

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";

    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

            System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                           price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch`and `throws` for the same exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try-catch is used whenever you are calling a method that can throw an exception. In your case:

```
ResultSet rs = null;    
 try {
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Customer";
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for instance.

Comment: After doing that I have different errors.  I now have an error on the ; after query in the 3rd line.  All three rs have errors also

Answer (score 0):

The need for a try/catch can be found in the documentation for ResultSet. I would assume that executeQuery throws an exception for syntax errors in input SQL queries. Not sure, but getString may also throw an exception.

If executeQuery requires one...

```
ResultSet rs;
try
{
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String ln = rs.getString("FirstName");
        String ln1 = rs.getString("LastName");
        System.out.println(ln + " " + ln1);
    }
}
catch(/* whatever the exception class is called */ caughtException)
{
    System.out.println(caughtException); 
    // most Exceptions have "toString"

    // you can do whatever else when caught if necessary
}
```